# Pandas: Group by operation on dynamically selected columns with conditional filter

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
   Date        Group   Value   Duration
2018-01-01      A      20       30
2018-02-01      A      10       60
2018-01-01      B      15      180
2018-02-01      B      30      210
2018-03-01      B      25      238 
2018-01-01      C      10      235
2018-02-01      C      15      130
```

I want to use `group_by` dynamically i.e. do not wish to type the column names on which `group_by` would be applied. Specifically, I want to compute `mean` of each Group for last two months.

As we can see that not each Group's data is present in the above dataframe for all dates. So the tasks are as follows:

1. Add a dummy row based on the date, in case data pertaining to `Date = 2018-03-01`not present for each Group (e.g. add row for A and C).
2. Perform `group_by` to compute mean using last two month's `Value` and `Duration`.

So my approach is as follows:

For Task 1:

```
 s = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df['Date'].unique(),df['Group'].unique()],names=['Date','Group'])
 df = df.set_index(['Date','Group']).reindex(s).reset_index().sort_values(['Group','Date']).ffill(axis=0)
```

can we have a better method for achieving the 'add row' task? The reference is found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62124939/pandas-inserting-new-row-based-on-date-condition-for-each-group)

For Task 2:

```
def cond_grp_by(df,grp_by:str,cols_list:list,*args):
    df_grp = df.groupby(grp_by)[cols_list].transform(lambda x : x.tail(2).mean())
    return df_grp
df_cols = df.columns.tolist()
df = cond_grp_by(dealer_f_filt,'Group',df_cols)
```

Reference of the above approach is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50405283/dynamically-select-dataframe-columns-for-groupby-in-python).

The above code is throwing `IndexError : Column(s) ['index','Group','Date','Value','Duration'] already selected`

The expected output is

```
Group    Value    Duration
  A       10         60 <---------   Since a row is added for 2018-03-01 with 
  B       27.5      224              same value as 2018-02-01,we are 
  C       15        130 <---------   computing mean for last two values
```

Comment: kindly post ur expected output

Comment: added the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) instead `transform` if need output filled by aggregate values:

```
def cond_grp_by(df,grp_by:str,cols_list:list,*args):
    return df.groupby(grp_by)[cols_list].agg(lambda x : x.tail(2).mean()).reset_index()
df = cond_grp_by(df,'Group',df_cols)
print (df)
  Group  Value  Duration
0     A   10.0      60.0
1     B   27.5     224.0
2     C   15.0     130.0
```

If need last value per groups use [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
def cond_grp_by(df,grp_by:str,cols_list:list,*args):
    return df.groupby(grp_by)[cols_list].last().reset_index()
df = cond_grp_by(df,'Group',df_cols)
```

Comment: jezrael: if I use `last` as transformation i.e. `lambda x : x.last()`, it is asking for `last() missing 1 required positional argument: 'offset'`. Why do I need to provide the same?

Comment: @pythondumb - If need last is necessary use `df.groupby(grp_by)[cols_list].last()`. Error means `last` [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) is implemented only for groupby object, so cannot be used in `agg` (then is called [`Series.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.last.html) - it is different function, last value by datetimeindex)

Comment: jazrael: can you please stab the first question?